# In `Yii2` I'm passing model value but its showing as a null

Tags: php, yii2

> There is my controller code

```
 if ($this->request->isPost) {
            $model->created_by = Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
            $model->created_at = date('Y/m/d');
            // echo $model->created_at;die;
            if ($model->load($this->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
                return $this->redirect(['index', 'id' => $model->id]);
            }
        }
```

> and there is my model rule

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['deduction_type'], 'required'],
        [['created_at'], 'safe'],
        [['created_by'], 'integer'],
        [['deduction_type'], 'string', 'max' => 100],
    ];
}
```

My problem is, every time I pass the value in create_at and create_by data save in database as a null.
I want my actual value in db.

Comment: Change `$model->created_at = date('Y-m-d');` as database table date format is `Y-m-d`. then only `safe` will work.

Comment: @Anant-Alivetodie  as you say I tried date('Y-m-d') and also tried date('Y-m-d H:i:s') but at the last it's passing Null value in db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of your way

```
 if ($this->request->isPost) {
            //Move that two Lines inside the if
            $model->created_by = Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
            $model->created_at = date('Y/m/d');

            // echo $model->created_at;die;
            if ($model->load($this->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
                return $this->redirect(['index', 'id' => $model->id]);
            }
        }
```

I usually do the following:

```
 if ($this->request->isPost) {
            if ($model->load($this->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
                $model->created_by = Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
                $model->created_at = date('Y/m/d');
                $model->save();
                return $this->redirect(['index', 'id' => $model->id]);
            }
        }
```

`validate()`->Checks if the Inputs are Correct according to your rules.
Afterwards you know that the entries were correct and you can set your values.
This is my usual way of tackling this problem.
You can also wrap `$model->save();` with an `if` to check your changes as well and to catch the potential `false`of save().

Answer (score 0):

Check your POST, is it send empty filds created_at and created_by? don't send this fields in post and load() method will not replace it on null values.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: i was checked but data was not empty

Answer (score 0):

If you are really want to insert current user id and current time, use the BlameableBehavior and TimestampBehavior.

BlameableBehavior automatically fills the specified attributes with the current user ID.
https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-behaviors-blameablebehavior

TimestampBehavior automatically fills the specified attributes with the current timestamp.
https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-behaviors-timestampbehavior